# How to make a conditional search on associated tables in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I currently have 5 tables: `branch`, `services`, `regular_prices`, `services_prices` and `price_list`.
[image]

I will provide 2 parameters. Theses are `branch_id` and `total_amount`.

I am trying to make a query that can get the current service of a branch (the `branch` is 1:1 with the `service` table. Then the service table can have multiple `regular_prices` and multiple `special_prices`) then if the `service_service_id` of the branch is 1 we will query on the `reqular_prices` table and if it's 2 we will query on the `special_prices`.

Then select the proper `regular_price` or `special_price` according to the current date today.

then select from the proper `price_list` entry depending on the `total_amount` (`total_amount` >= `price_list.minimum_price` and `total_amount` <= `price_list.max_price`)

```
 SELECT    *
FROM      branch b
LEFT JOIN regular_prices rp
ON        rp.services_service_id = b.services_service_id
LEFT JOIN special_prices sp
ON        sp.services_service_id = b.services_service_id
LEFT JOIN prices_list pl
ON        (
                    rp.regular_prices_id = pl.preset_branch_effective_rate_id
          OR        sp.special_prices_id = pl.preset_branch_promo_effective_rate_id )
WHERE     branch.branch_id = 1
AND       (
                    rp.effective_date <= '2020-12-11'
          OR        (
                              sp.start_date <= '2020-12-11'
                    AND       sp.end_date >= '2020-12-11' )
          AND       pl.minimum_amount <= 1100000
          AND       pl.maximum_amount >= 1100000 }
```

Comment: If the relation is 1:1, why are they separate tables? And, for further help, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I added a sample query. But I have no idea if I am doing the right thing.

Comment: Sure. Hence my comment above. Just follow the suggestions in the accepted answer at the linked question.